# Python 'key error' while building dictionary dynamically (On the fly)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I get the error onthis line of code -

```
result_dict['strat'][k]['name'] = current_comps[0].strip()
The error is : Keyerror: 'strat'
```

I have an input line

```
PERSON1 @@ CAR1 # ENTRY : 0 | EXIT : 0 @@ CAR2 # M1 : YES : 10/01/17 02:00 | M2 : NO : 10/02/16 03:00 | M3 : NO : 05/07/17 11:00 | M4 : YES : 01/01/16 03:00 @@ TRUCK # M3 : NO : 03/01/17 03:45 | M23 : NO : 01/01/14 07:00 | M27 : YES : 02/006/18 23:00
```

I 'm looking to parse this input to generate the output detailed below. As part of this, I'm trying to build a dictionary inserting both keys & values dynamically. I'm having a lot of problems doing this.

Could I please request help on this?

Here is what I've tried so far -

```
# File read
f = open('input_data', 'r')
file_cont = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

#json template

# Initialize dictionary
result_arr = []
result_dict = {}
k = 0

for item in file_cont:
    strat = item.split('@@')
    result_dict['Person'] = strat[0].strip()
    j = 1
    while j < len(strat):
        # Split various components of the main line
        current_comps = strat[j].split('#')

        # Name of strat being parsed
        result_dict['strat'][k]['name'] = current_comps[0].strip()

        # tfs across the various time frames
        tfs = current_comps[1].split('|')

        # First travel mode
        if current_comps[0].strip() == 'CAR1':
            temp_low_arr = tfs[0].split(':')
            temp_high_arr = tfs[1].split(':')
            result_dict['strat'][k]['Entry'] = temp_low_arr[1].strip()
            result_dict['strat'][k]['Exit'] = temp_high_arr[1].strip()

        # Second travel mode
        elif current_comps[0].strip() == 'CAR2':
            z = 0
            while z < len(tfs):
                # Split components of the sign
                sign_comp_car_2 = tfs[z].split(':')
                result_dict['strat'][k]['tf'][z]['path'] = sign_comp_ma_cross[0].strip()
                result_dict['strat'][k]['tf'][z]['sign'] = sign_comp_ma_cross[1].strip()
                result_dict['strat'][k]['tf'][z]['sign_time'] = sign_comp_ma_cross[2].strip()
                z += 1

        # Third travel mode
        elif current_comps[0].strip() == 'CAR3':
            b = 0
            while b < len(tfs):
                # Split components of the sign
                sign_car_3 = tfs[z].split(':')
                result_dict['strat'][k]['tf'][b]['path'] = sign_all_term[0].strip()
                result_dict['strat'][k]['tf'][b]['sign'] = sign_all_term[1].strip()
                result_dict['strat'][k]['tf'][b]['sign_time'] = sign_all_term[2].strip()
                b += 1
    j += 1
k += 1
```

***Expected output***

```
[{  
   "Person":"",
   "Transport":[  
      {  
         "Name":"CAR1",
         "Entry":"0",
         "Exit":"0"
      },
      {  
         "name":"CAR2:",
         "tf":[  
            {  
               "path":"M1",
               "sign":"YES",
               "sign_time":"10/01/17 02:00"
            },
            {  
               "path":"M2",
               "sign":"NO",
               "sign_time":"10/02/16 03:00"
            },
            {  
               "path":"M3",
               "sign":"NO",
               "sign_time":"05/07/17 11:00"
            },
            {  
               "path":"M4",
               "sign":"YES",
               "sign_time":"01/01/16 03:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"CAR3",
         "tf":[  
            {  
               "path":"M3",
               "sign":"NO",
               "sign_time":"03/01/17 03:45"
            },
            {  
               "path":"M23",
               "sign":"NO",
               "sign_time":"01/01/14 07:00"
            },
            {  
               "path":"M27",
               "sign":"Yes",
               "sign_time":"02/006/18 23:00"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}]
```

Comment: What's `result_dict`?

Comment: your `j` and `k` increments are aligned to their respective outermost loops. Are you sure you're not missing a level of indentation there?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when you try to assign the `['name']` field in `result_dict['strat'][k]` when `result_dict['strat'][k]` hasn't been initialized yet. Before you run your for-loop, the dictionary has no key called `strat`.
Now you could have done something like `result_dict['strat'] = dict()` (assigning an object to that key in the dict), but when you further subscript it using `result_dict['strat'][k]`, it will try to resolve that first, by accessing `result_dict['strat']`, expecting either a subscriptable collection or a dictionary in return. However, since that key doesn't exist yet, it throws you the error.

What you could do instead is initialize a default dictionary:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

...

resultdict = defaultdict(dict)
...
```

Otherwise, in your existing code, you could initialize a dict within `result_dict` before entering the loop.